# IntelliJ - Filter the out *Test.java classes from global search (shift+shift) result

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Small question regarding IntelliJ please.

I am currently running the latest the 2020.3 version of IntelliJ, my question is applicable to both Community and Ultimate version.

By "Global search", I am referring to the search after pressing shift + shift.

So, I have a java class called `MyClass.java`. and for the class, I have a test class, `MyClassTest.java`

(I am illustrating this example with one pair of Class.java + ClassTest.java, but as you can imagine, it is for all of them).

When I global search "MyClass", the result that always some first is for some reason "MyClassTest.java"

How can I configure IntelliJ to filter out all Test.java, or at least, put MyClass.java as first result instead of MyClassTest.java please?

Thank you

Comment: Try with *Go to class* (Ctrl+N) instead.

Comment: Yes, and there are many other ways to go to the class directly instead of the test class. But my question is really about the result of a global search, where I do not know the name of the class for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is really about the result of a global search, where I do not know the name of the class for instance

Why don't use *Go to file* for such cases? There you also can specify your custom-created [**scope**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html) where you can exclude files you do not want to include into a search or use the predefined **Project production files** scope which excludes all test sources.

[image]

For quick access use the shortcut for `Go To File` action, then to activate the scope use corresponding shortcuts in **Go To File** popup:

[image]

Comment: It is indeed a correct solution, so accepting it. But now, on each search, I need to click Project Files, scroll down all the way to Other, to click on My Scope 

Comment: Updated the answer about shortcuts.